# Python How to search through list X for element Y. Element Y is a list itself whose elements may not be in order as listed in X

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
X = ['rgb','rg870','rg1200','rg1550']
```

My second list is:

```
Y = [870,r,g]
```

I want to search in the `X` list and for the combination of `Y` list even if the order doesn't match and return the element index.

This should return index of 1. #At lest I think its position 1 as the first element is 0?

Comment: Can you be more precise how your variable Y looks like? Are those three separated values, or a string "870,r,g"?

Comment: they are 3 separate values that I combine into a list. I have 6 values that I search through (r,g,b,870,1200,1550) to find the 3 highest average. I then combine these three into a list and I'm trying to find the combination of these three in my first list.

Comment: Please include the code you've already tried. Read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np

X = ['rgb','rg870','rg1200','rg1550']

Y = ['870','r','g']

result = np.where([sorted(''.join(Y))==sorted(x) for x in X])[0]
print(result)
```

Code explanation:

- `''.join(Y)` makes you move from a list `Y` to a string with all elements separated by an empty character.
- `sorted(''.join(Y))` orders your newly created string.
- `sorted(x)` orders at the same way `x`, which is iteratively an element of `X` trhough list comprehension.
- By comparing the sorted strings, you ensure that all the characters of `Y` are contained in the element `x` in the same number, even if original order was not the same.
- Using `np.where(_)` searches for the position where the matching occurs. Since generally `np.where` is for matrices, you need to select the first element only: `np.where(_)[0]`.
- Finally you print your result which is a list of positions where the matching occurs. If you are sure that only one match occurs, then you may extract it simply doing `result = np.where(_)[0][0]`, thus taking element 0 of your list of results.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great, however the result is in brackets. How do I get the result with just the index number without the brackets?

Comment: Hi John. As of last point, if you just use `result = np.where(_)[0][0]` you get element 0 of your list, thus you'd get rid of the brackets, but you will only have one element even if more than one match occur.

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
# I have a list: 
X = ['rgb','rg870','rg1200','rg1550']

# My second list is: 
Y = ['870','r','g']

# I want to search in the X list and for the combination
# of Y list even if the order doesn't match and return the element index.

# This should return index of 1. #At lest I think its 
# position 1 as the first element is 0?
# You don't mind if I use more descriptive variable names?

def find_combo(full_ids,segments):
  for idx,full_id in enumerate(full_ids):
    is_match = True
    for segment in segments:
      if segment in full_id:
        pass
      else:
        is_match = False
        break
    if is_match:
      return idx
    else:
      continue
    
find_combo(X,Y)
>>> 1
```